# How to remove the bounce off colliding objects in box2d?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I am trying to delete an object in `box2d` when two objects collide.

When my two objects do collide, one of the object bounces off the other. It does delete the other object, but I want it to make it look like it went through rather than a bounce.

I have my body Def type set to `b2_staticBody`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the body's fixture to be a sensor:

```
fixture->SetSensor(true);
```

You then create a contact listener (`class MyContactListener : public b2ContactListener`) that detects collisions in the BeginContact method and checks if one of the colliding objects is of this special kind. A good way of doing that is by using these two methods:

```
/// Get the user data pointer that was provided in the body definition.
void* GetUserData() const;

/// Set the user data. Use this to store your application specific data.
void SetUserData(void* data);
```

You need to be a bit familiar with C++ to pull it off.